# jQuery show() panel not working

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to create a page with the map of europe on the left and on the right a panel that appears when I click on the desired country.

My problem at the moment is the panel, because I am in trouble creating it.

This is the code of the page without the panel:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
$('#navigation li a').append('')
$('#navigation li a').append('')
$('#navigation .hover').css("filter","alpha(opacity=00)");
$('#navigation li a').hover(function() {

// Stuff that happens when you hover on + the stop()
$('.hover', this).stop().animate({
    'opacity': 1
}, 700,'easeOutSine')

},function() {

// Stuff that happens when you unhover + the stop()
$('.hover', this).stop().animate({
    'opacity': 0
}, 700, 'easeOutQuad')

})
});

$(function($){
    $('#map').cssMap({'size' : 670});
});
</script>

<body>

<div id="wrap">
    <div id="page">
        <div id="map-content">          
            <div id="map">
            <ul class="europe">
                <li class="es"><a href="#espana" id=show>Espana</a></li>
                <li class="uk"><a href="#unitedkingdom">United Kingdom</a></li>
                <li class="fr"><a href="#france">France</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

    <button id=hide>hide()</button>
    <button id=reset>Reset</button>

    <p>Hello, this show() and hide() example</p>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    $("ul.europe li a show").click(function () {
       $("p").show('fast');
    });

    $("#hide").click(function () {
       $("p").hide(1000);
    });

    $("#reset").click(function(){
        location.reload();
    });
    </script>

   </div>   
</div>
```

In this part of the code the first function is for a menu, the second one call a JS for the map.

I thought to use .show(), but I really do not know how to manage them. If I click on Espana nothing happen. I think that the problem is in the '$("ul.europe li a show")'.
Or use also something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/rionmonster/J8U25/

Any help please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`show` is an id, so just simply use `$("#show")` as the id should always be unique to the document.

---

**Update**

I have recreated your code in [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2TNTN/) and discovered what I think is the problem.  There is no `.cssMap` in jQuery, it's just `.css`.

So change...

```
$('#map').cssMap({'size' : 670});
```

To...

```
$('#map').css({'size' : 670});
```

(You still need to use the `$("#show")` as I mentioned in the first part of this answer in the appropriate place)

If you don't already, I would strongly recommend you use something like [Firebug for Firefox](http://getfirebug.com) or the developer tools in IE8+ and Chrome, as then this would have been easy to spot.

Comment: I tried but I don't know why it doesn't work. It works only if I place show in a button, like the others. <button id=show>show()</button>

Comment: I've played with your JSFiddle, and can get it to work with [this update](http://jsfiddle.net/J8U25/455/).  Are you sure there aren't multiple `id="show"` or anything like that?

Comment: @Mark, I don't think it will make a difference (because the `href` in the link is a local anchor reference), but try putting `event.preventDefault();` in your `click` handler

Comment: sorry for the late, I tried it also, but I really don't know why it doesn't work. I will try some other tests to find the problem, I spent 3 days on this and cannot figure out. When I'll be at home I will try. Thank you for now for the time you spent on this.

Comment: @Mark, have you looked at [the latest JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2TNTN/) which is working as you're wanting.  This is after changing `.cssMap` to `.css`, and changing `$("ul.europe li a show")` to `$("#show")`.  So I can't see how it's still not working for you

Comment: If I try it in a brand new page, it is working if I try it in my already created page, it is not working.
If I try to use the show() in a button, it works great. Instead in my country it is not.

Comment: In that case @Mark, I don't think there is anything I can do for you - I believe I've worked out the problem in your original question.  I would seriously recommend using a developer tool (like Firebug) which will really help you discover what is going on

Comment: I accept it as answer because it works in a standalone file, thank you.
I will do other test and I will hope to fix it. Thank you for your time again.

Comment: ok, thank you @Mark.  Good luck tracking it down - it will probably be exceptionally easy, and you'll kick yourself once you finally spot it.

Comment: Thx I think so and that's why I am angry :D

Answer (score 5):

What you are doing above looks a little over complicated. I have wrote a basic JS fiddle for the showing and hiding of divs based on rels from an a tag finding a div with a particular ID.

http://jsfiddle.net/2Be9a/17/ - updated latest fiddle

Comment: thank you for the fiddle, also this is not working in my code..... :( but this is very close to my thoughts.

Comment: This basic feature is perfect, in my thoughts I'd like to use a slide panel from right to left.
1) no panel;
2) when click on a country the panel appears sliding from right to left and stay until I will click on another country.

But I have to do it, I don't like to ask people to do code for me, but thank you anyway, I really appreciated it.
I prefer to try to write things by myself and then ask for help :P

Hope you understand.

Comment: hahah omg this is awesome!! I have to find the bug in my code and I will use this last fiddle. Thank you again SO SO much!

Comment: ah sorry i missed your update to the above, I have given you a helping hand there. Its jsut a case of using active classes to determain where the user is at and jquery animate with toggle and width to hide and show the panels. The key thing to get it working Right to Left is the CSS position of the .text elements , they need to be fixed or positioned to the right of its containing element. Good luck with this :)

Comment: It seems that the JS cannot work on the map I created because on the map there is another JS action.
When the map is generated, for example, the <ul> instead of <ul class="europe"> will become <ul class="europe css-map">. That's could be a problem??